# pcap_loop with filter does not capture any packet

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap

I encounter a problem with the pcap filter. Here is part of the code:

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void pcap_fatal(const char *failed_in, const char *errbuf) {
printf("Fatal error in %s: %s\n", failed_in, errbuf);
exit(1);
}

int main() {
struct pcap_pkthdr header;
const u_char *packet;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
char *device;
pcap_t *pcap_handle;
int i;
struct  bpf_program filter;
char filter_str[1000];
pcap_dumper_t *pd;

device = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
if(device == NULL)
    pcap_fatal("pcap_lookupdev", errbuf);

printf("Sniffing on device %s\n", device);

pcap_handle = pcap_open_live(device, 4096, 1, 0, errbuf);
if(pcap_handle == NULL)
    pcap_fatal("pcap_open_live", errbuf);

// Set the packet filter
sprintf(filter_str, "port 80");
if(pcap_compile(pcap_handle, &filter, filter_str, 0, 0) == -1)
    fatal("create filter");
if(pcap_setfilter(pcap_handle, &filter) == -1)
    fatal("install filter");

for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    packet = pcap_next(pcap_handle, &header);
    printf("Got a %d bytes packet\n", header.len);
    dump(packet, header.len);
}

pd = pcap_dump_open(pd, "-");

pcap_loop(pcap_handle, -1, &pcap_dump, (char *)pd);

pcap_close(pcap_handle);

}
```

`pcap_next()` captures packet well, and the `dump()` function is used to dump the data in the packet. But the `pcap_loop` does not capture any packet and after the packet capture in the `for` loop, it just get stuck.

I am programming on ubuntu running in virtualbox with the network adapter set to "bridge", could it be the problem? Or it is just something wrong with the code.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably your problem:

```
pd = pcap_dump_open(pd, "-");
```

The signature for [`pcap_dump_open()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_dump_open) is:

```
pcap_dumper_t *pcap_dump_open(pcap_t *p, const char *fname);
```

You probably meant to pass in `pcap_handle` instead:

```
pd = pcap_dump_open(pcap_handle, "-");
```

Comment: Ahh this is an embarrassing mistake. Thanks for the help

Comment: Make sure to pay attention to the compiler warnings. The compiler should have informed you of this particular mistake.